# Keep Gcov Test name in GCDA files

Tags: gcov, lcov, gcovr

After having performed my test coverage on my product using lcov (for C++ dev), i'd like to draw a matrix to have the correspondence between the test name and the files it covers.
The idea is to have a quick view of the code covered by 1 test file.

eg:

xxxx    |file 1 |file 2 |file 3 |file 4 | file 5 |
test 1  |   YES |  NO   |   YES   | YES | YES    |
test 2  |   YES |  NO   |   NO    | No  | NO     |
test 3  |   YES |  YES   |   NO   | NO |  YES    |

In my project, I need to run thousands of tests to check the coverage of thousands of files, so the matrix will be huge.

Unfortunately, it seems that by design GCOV does not works this way, because we will have only one set of gcda files that covers the whole code, and it looks not possible to determines which test covers which part of the code.

The only solution I could imagine is the following one:

```
for current_test in all_tests do:
    run 1 current_test
    retrieve gcda -> .info file
    extract from the .info file the name of covered code files
    append the matrix with current_test / code filename
```

The problem is that it will be extremely long, because to do so, it will take around 5 min for 1 test... I'll spend weeks to wait...

Any idea would be very welcomed.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the gcov data does not include test names, and they must be added in post-processing. Therefore, your sequential loop is the sensible approach if you stay within gcov-based coverage collection.

Workarounds you can try:

- Run your tests with an appropriate [GCOV_PREFIX](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Cross-profiling.html) variable so that the coverage is written into a different directory, rather than next to your object files.
- Use a different coverage tool. E.g. kcov performs runtime instrumentation and writes the coverage results into a directory you specify. However, the coverage data formats are not usable for gcov-based tools.
- Distribute your tests across multiple machines.

My guess is that GCOV_PREFIX is likely to work in your scenario so that you can easily run your tests in parallel. This variable is a bit fiddly because you need to know the absolute paths of your object files, but it's probably easier to figure that out than it is to wait multiple days for your coverage matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this soon :)